# How to disable lasso selection in jQuery Selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

I am trying the [jQuery UI selectable plugin](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/#default). Where I want to select one item at a time, without using the lasso selection.

[image]

I want to disable the lasso selection, is it possible.

Comment: So don't instantiate the selectable library in those instances...?

Comment: No, I am asking if there is an option to do so?

Comment: Not natively. http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/. You could probably hack something together using the events the library exposes, but at that point I'd ask, why even bother using the library at all? Just toggle classes on click of the elements.

Comment: I want to select one element at a time and not through the lasso